# Ceph behavior when pool quota is reached

Tags: ceph

According to the information from http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/release-notes/, from Infernalis release, ceph changed default behavior when pool quota is reached (When a pool quota is reached, librados operations now block indefinitely, the same way they do when the cluster fills up. (Previously they would return -ENOSPC.) By default, a full cluster or pool will now block. If your librados application can handle ENOSPC or EDQUOT errors gracefully, you can get error returns instead by using the new librados OPERATION_FULL_TRY flag.)

Does anyone know, is there any way to change this behavior back to return ENOSPC when pool quota is reached?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: https://github.com/ceph/ceph/pull/13615
And if you browser the source code,
in PrimaryLogPG.cc prepare_transaction() function,
you can ignore the check of CEPH_OSD_FLAG_FULL_TRY flag,
and return ENOSPC once the pool FULL flag is set.